# How to set the CAlayer bounds from my view controller for multiple subview

Tags: iphone, ios, calayer, drawrect, bounds

I am new to iOS programming. Please help me to sort out the following issue

1. I have one set of view controller(.h, .m and .XIB)
2. I have one set of view(.h&.m)

3.The view class is responsible for drawing gauge using
-->drawRect
-->CALayer and sublayers
In this view I have initialize method, and this method only i set the bounds for my layers and sublayers

here i am pasting some sort of code..

```
- (void)initialize {
    CGFloat span = fmin(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    frameLayerObject_ = [[OuterFrameLayer alloc] init];
    frameLayer = [[CALayer layer] retain];
    frameLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(250, 50, 710, 320);
    frameLayer.position = self.frame.origin;
    frameLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
    frameLayer.delegate = self.frameLayerObject;
    [self.layer addSublayer:frameLayer];
    [frameLayer setNeedsDisplay];

    self.minValue = 0.0;
    self.maxValue = 100.0;
    self.tickStartAngle = M_PI;
    self.tickArcLength = M_PI
    self.lineWidth = span / 200.0;
    self.tickLength = span / 12.0;
    self.minorTickLength = span / 16.0;
    self.tickInset = self.lineWidth;
    textLabel_ = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 3.0 * self.frame.size.height / 10.0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height / 10.0)];
    self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:span / 17.77];
    [self addSubview:self.textLabel];

    needleLayerObject_ = [[gaugeNeedle alloc] init];
    self.needleLayerObject.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    needleLayer = [[CALayer layer] retain];
    needleLayer.bounds = self.bounds;
    needleLayer.position =CGPointMake(((self.bounds.size.width / 2.0)), ((self.bounds.size.height / 2.0)));

    needleLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
    needleLayer.delegate = self.needleLayerObject;
    [self.layer addSublayer:needleLayer];
    [needleLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

In my view controller, I have created 5 views in my xib and .h and i am assigning the same view class for all the 5 views.

Now the problem is, all 5 views differ in their position and bounds. But my drawRect view class has only one set of bounds for all views. So if I hardcode the bounds and position in initialize method with respect to one view, the remaining 4 views are getting affected. Please let me know if u know where i am going wrong.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

each of your five views should be executing the draw code relative to their own coordinate space, and there would be no problem.  Use self.bounds as the rectangle in your drawing code and the five should all draw identically in their own space.  Don't use self.frame, this is in the parent view's coordinate space, and introduces the problem you are experiencing.

You may also want to experiment with the clipsToBounds property, when this is set to YES a UIView can't draw beyond its own borders.